# Working with responsive videos and padding

Tags: css, padding

I've put together a quick website for a friend for a bunch of speakers she has. Everything is great however for some reason the padding I'm putting on the bottom of my video container is making it so that if there is no video there there is this huge space. For the life of me I don't know what else to do to have these videos responsive but have it so if there is no videos on the page it doesn't create this large gap.

This is a snippet of code from a website I've taken it from to make all videos responsive (you then wrap the video embed code in a couple divs).

```
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my CSS for the video container

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 54.5%;
    padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is an example of the huge gap when there is no video submitted - http://spellbindersspeakers.org/speaker/yvonne-thompson

This is what it should look like when there are video and testimonials submitted - http://spellbindersspeakers.org/speaker/roslyn-franken

If there is no video for the speaker I don't want to have this large gap. I just want the testimonials to rest right under the buttons or content from the top.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit of a hack, but using the `:empty` css selector on the video container would fix you up here.

```
.video-container:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Of course, no displaying the video container element in the markup at all would be best, if there aren't any videos.

Comment: That works. I've never used that css selector before. Thanks! 
It's all dynamically populated (if else kind of thing with a wordpress plugin) so I wouldn't be able to take it completely out.